# Arrange comma delineated responses into a bulleted list

Tags: google-sheets

I used the following formula to help create my solution and used a tilda as I can't find the code for a bullet.  My question is how do I add a tilda to the beginning of the first response?

**This is the formula:**

={"A: PHYSICAL ACCOMMODATIONS: (if any)";arrayformula(substitute(U2:U,"., ",Char(10)&Char(126)&" "))}

**This is how the data comes in:**

Teachers will provide STUDENT with preferential seating, as needed away from distractions., Teachers will provide STUDENT with preferential seating, as needed near the teacher for reassurance., Teachers will provide STUDENT with preferential seating, as needed near positive role models.

**This is how it looks with my formula:**

Teachers will provide STUDENT with preferential seating, as needed away from distractions

~ Teachers will provide STUDENT with preferential seating, as needed near the teacher for reassurance

~ Teachers will provide STUDENT with preferential seating, as needed near positive role models.

**This is how I want it to look (ideally I would prefer a bullet if possible:**

~ Teachers will provide STUDENT with preferential seating, as needed away from distractions

~ Teachers will provide STUDENT with preferential seating, as needed near the teacher for reassurance

~ Teachers will provide STUDENT with preferential seating, as needed near positive role models.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pamela.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string literal like `"• "` and `if(len())`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "A: PHYSICAL ACCOMMODATIONS: (if any)"; 
    if( 
      len(U2:U), 
      substitute("• " & U2:U, "., ", char(10) & "• "), 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ) 
  } 
)
```